# Prepopulate Name and lookup field value from related list new button

Tags: visualforce, urlhacking, list-button, default-value, new

On a custom object, I've managed to auto populate the custom object's name field to a default value using below custom vf page code:

```
<apex:page standardController="CustomObject__c" recordSetVar="CO"
    action="{!URLFOR($Action.CustomObject__c.New, null, ['Name'='Default Value'], true)}"  
/>
```

Now in addition to the Name field I also want to auto populate a Lookup field(Parent record value) on the Custom object.

How can i achieve this without url hacking or without overriding standard layout with visualforce page.

Comment: You're ruling out the two most obvious implementations. Can you justify why you want to avoid them? I think they might be the only two *options*.

Comment: I am trying to see, if there is any other way to achieve this

Comment: The point is that there is presently no choice but to "hack" because ideas like this [Apex describe information should also give Field ID's](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000gM7mAAE) remain unimplemented by Salesforce. Vote for this idea. Meanwhile all you can do is hack.

Comment: Why don't populating the lookup in the standar controller initialization? Here two links that may help: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_ApexPages_StandardController_getRecord.htm, https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_pages_standardcontroller.htm